# How to set determined records at top of select query?

Tags: sql, select

I have a db table.
I want to when select query run turn the result which first 5 records are specific and not ordered, below these 5 records came ordered records.

```
  id    name 
   1      a
   2      b
   3      c
   4      d
```

i want to sort like below:

```
  id    name
   3      c 
   1      a
   2      b
   4      d
```

Comment: could you please rephrase your question and add some sample data with what you have and what do you want returned?

Comment: seriously ?? no related codes, not even an example of what actaully you need... how are we suppose to help you.... i guess the best answer you could get with this question is ... **first run query then, select specific 5 first and order others later** ..:)

Comment: guess what he want is to separate ordered and disordered data ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** Based on the sample data and desire output that you provided you can do this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN id = 3 THEN 0
            WHEN id = 1 THEN 1
            WHEN id = 2 THEN 2
            WHEN id = 4 THEN 3
            ELSE 4 
          END, id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5ba2/1)** demo (**SQL Server**)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ba2c/1)** demo (**MySql**)

Another way is to grab first five records in one select, all others in second; inject user defined column (`n` in the example below) to both selects with appropriate values (`0` and `1` in the example below). Then union them and in the outer select order by this column first and apply other ordering rules as necessary.

```
SELECT id
  FROM
(
  SELECT t.*, 0 n
    FROM Table1 t
   WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*, 1 n 
    FROM Table1 t
   WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
) q
 ORDER BY q.n, CASE WHEN q.n = 1 THEN q.id END DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a76e/7)** demo (**SQL Server**)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac352/2)** demo (**MySql**)

***On a side note:** When you ask a sql query related question please **always** provide sample data, desired output, your current query, and information about what RDBMS you are using and its version.*

Comment: +1 For Nice way of answering..